# Chart.js line chart not showing point on top most value

Tags: chart.js, chart.js2

Just like to ask why the point is not displayed on the top most line (blue line, red line is showing the point [sample chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsRai.png)). I'm using version 2.7, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [bug listed in v2.7.0 with this issue](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/4790).

Here are some options, most of them are listed in the issue above.

- Try v2.6.0
- Add some extra space on top using [stepSize option](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/linear.html?h=stepsize)
- Wait for a bug fix

Comment: I believe this is now fixed in 2.7.1

Comment: @tyelford This bug still occurs in 2.7.2.

Comment: version 2.8.0 fixed it